# what's with the trailing slashes in URLs?

Tags: node.js, http, nginx

So, there are a ton of questions here on SO about trailing slashes (help me remove, help me add, and so on). Mine relates to "help me remove" with an additional, "what is causing them?"

I have a `nodejs`+`expressjs` powered web site behind an `nginx` proxy. I have URLs without any trailing slashes, and yet, the browser is adding a trailing slash even though the Chrome/Safari developer tools or Firebug show the request without a trailing slash. So, in the debug tools I can see the request made (as intended) to `http://localhost:3000/resource?id=resource_id` but in the browser address bar that shows up as `http://localhost:3000/resource/?id=resource_id`

As mentioned above, I would like to not have the trailing slash added by the browser, and two, I would like to understand why that is happening in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** This [link](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html) might be helpful.

> Historically, it’s common for URLs with a trailing slash to indicate a
>   directory, and those without a trailing slash to denote a file.

To remove trailing slashes via `nginx` simply add following statement inside your virtual host file in the `server {}` block configuration:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

Comment: thanks, I will follow your instruction. However, it is still not clear to me as to what is causing that slash to be inserted. I am not doing it, and it is not being inserted in all instances. Only a few of the routes get the slash appended. Why?